# Dropdown doesn't display inside navbar Laravel 6.0

Tags: php, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

***I have my dropdown that i want to show in my view but it doesn't deploy ,i cant see the options in my dropdown , how can i solve it***

- Below i will let `index function()` that shows that view, the part of the dropdown in the view and my scripts

***`Index function()`***

```php
public function index(Request $request,$correo)
    {
        return view('home.homeRegister')->with('correo',$correo);
    }
```

***View***

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>ACAVUCAB</title>
    </head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark  ">
  <div class="container">
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <!-- Authentication Links -->
          <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown link
            </a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

***scripts***

```js
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I fix it putting these***

***In the `<head>`***

```html
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

***`<script>` below***

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you test this code? Maybe you forget to add bootstrap js scripts :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark  ">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="container">
   <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <!-- Authentication Links -->
          <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown link
            </a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
  </ul>
 </div>
</nav>
```

If this answer is not enough. Please give more info.

Comment: Put it, but still doesn't work i dont know why ,it only happens in that view,i can show all nav part but its too long so i only show the dropdown

Comment: You wrote 'Dropdown doesn't display inside navbar Laravel'. If you run my code, click the Dropdown and can open. If this solution is not, check your own project's code, maybe you have forgotten something. I want to help you, but I'm sorry, I can't understand correctly.

Comment: Yes i notice that your code works, thanks for trying to help, i did just put how i solve it